# How to deal with "Django error - Matching query does not exist" without breaking your code?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I came across this error where I was trying to retrieve a user using a query from the database.
Below was my initial code which wanted to retrieve a user from a model called `Order` with the object `writer`

```
def assigned(request):
    orders = Order.objects.get(writer=request.user)
    if orders:
        return render(request, 'mainapp/assigned.html', {'orders': orders})   
    else:
        return render (request, 'mainapp/assigned.html')
```

However, after running my page I got a `DoesNotExist: Comment matching query does not exist` Error. This was not the correct way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to going around this was to use an exception; a specific one.
The `django.core.exceptions` module has a way of solving this if you need to make query retrivals only if the user exists in the context. In my case it was if the `OneToOneField` in the `Order` contained the instance of a `user` object. If it did not then we should render something else instead of displaying the horrific error which is not user friendly.
I achieved this by importing `from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist`  and changing my view function to:

```
def assigned(request):
    try:
        orders = Order.objects.get(writer=request.user)
        if orders:
            return render(request, 'mainapp/assigned.html', {'orders': orders})   
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'mainapp/assigned.html')
```

This way I rendered the page without the user model if at all I did not need it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try/except:

```
def assigned(request):
    try:
        orders = Order.objects.get(writer=request.user)  
    except Order.DoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'mainapp/assigned.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'mainapp/assigned.html', {'orders': orders})
```

But the exceptions could make your code slower. I recommend using `Object.objects.filter`, and validate if the given queryset exists.

```
def assigned(request):
    orders = Order.objects.filter(writer=request.user)  
    if orders.exists():
        # Now, to select the first and only order instance, you could use orders[0]
        return render(request, 'mainapp/assigned.html', {'orders': orders[0]})
    else:
        return render(request, 'mainapp/assigned.html')
```